# How to change background color of gedit embedded terminal

Tags: 10.04, command-line, gedit

How can I change the background color of gedit embedded terminal?

I have tried changing my normal terminal (ctrl+alt+t) background and restarting gedit - but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal/284132#284132

Comment: A much better solution is to use gconf-editor. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal