# Make gedit embedded terminal colours the same as the default terminal

Tags: command-line, gedit

I've just updated to 11.10 and now my embedded terminal in gedit does not match my default terminal. I hate looking at a white and black terminal. Does anyone know how to make the embedded terminal match the default terminal?

This is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I want my embedded terminal in gedit to match my default terminal.

Comment: This might be outdated, it seems to be the default behavior in 19.04

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the following packages installed:

   - [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)
   - [gconf-editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gconf-editor)
2. Open up `gconf-editor` and navigate to *apps ➜ gnome-terminal* and select a profile:

   [image]
3. Now open up `dconf-editor` and navigate to *org ➜ gnome ➜ gedit ➜ plugins ➜ terminal* and uncheck the *use-theme-colors* key:

   [image]
4. From gconf-editor, copy the values of the

   - **background-color**
   - **foreground-color**
   - **palette**

   over to the corresponding keys in dconf-editor. The embedded terminal should now match a regular gnome-terminal.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. Unfortunately when I am changing the values of the gedit terminal and then leave the edit text. The value I changed resets. Am I doing something stupid here?

Comment: Wait I hit enter instead of unfocusing. Works great thanks.

Comment: works great but my palette didn't seem to transfer. wish there were options in gedit->preferences->plugins->preferences.

Comment: This resolves the white on white issue on Precise (likely bug with the Ambiance theme)

Comment: In fact, the good way to do what you want to do is very close to the precedent solution, except on one little point. If you want to modify your palette colour of 'Gnome terminal', without re-modified it's value for the embedded terminal with dconf-editor, the solution is to simply delete the value of the palette with dconf-editor. Like in the precedent solution, which said to copy the value of the palette parameter, but just delete it (fill the value of embedded terminal plugin palette parameter to a blank).
--
Naereen.

Comment: I can confirm that Naereen's solution resets the colour profile to the one defined in my `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Changing my terminal's typeface and font size in dconf-editor has no effect, even after a restart of gedit.

Answer (score 18):

This is for gedit 3

Same problem here white on light gray.

I manually edited `/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/terminal.py`. Terminal used is xterm.

Search for:

```
fg = context.get_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
bg = context.get_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
```

I replace with

```
fg = Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1)
bg = Gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Info: `fg` = black text, `bg` = white background

Comment: I had to do `locate terminal.py` to find it on 13.10. It was hiding at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/terminal.py`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you haven't ticked *Use colors from system theme* then it should work:

[image]

Comment: This didnt work for me, I am running 10.04 if that makes any difference

Comment: Weird, because that's an updated live session of 10.04 in that screenshot. :(

Comment: I'm running 12.04 and I'm still having problems - can't read white on light gray.

Answer (score 1):

Open `gconf-editor` and go to `apps->gnome-terminal->profiles->Default`

- Uncheck the use-theme-colors option.
- Set foreground color: #FFFFFF
- Set background color: #000000

This will set the text to white and the background to black. It will set this for both the terminal and embedded terminal, if you would like to use different colors for each, then do this instead.

Open `gconf-editor` and go to `apps->gedit-2->plugins`

- Create a new key named use_theme_colors
- Set the type to: Boolean
- Set the value to: False
- Create a new key named foreground_color
- Set the type to: String
- Set the value to: #FFFFFF
- Create a new key named background_color
- Set the type to: String
- Set the value to: #000000

Edit the file `/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/terminal.py`

Underneath the line:

```
GCONF_PROFILE_DIR = "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default"
```

Add a new line:

```
GCONF_GEDIT_DIR = "/apps/gedit-2/plugins"
```

Then replace the lines:

```
if not gconf_get_bool(self.GCONF_PROFILE_DIR + "/use_theme_colors"):
fg_color = gconf_get_str(self.GCONF_PROFILE_DIR + "/foreground_color", None)
bg_color = gconf_get_str(self.GCONF_PROFILE_DIR + "/background_color", None)
```

With:

```
if not gconf_get_bool(self.GCONF_GEDIT_DIR + "/use_theme_colors"):
fg_color = gconf_get_str(self.GCONF_GEDIT_DIR + "/foreground_color", None)
bg_color = gconf_get_str(self.GCONF_GEDIT_DIR + "/background_color", None)
```

Now you can the set the colors for the embedded terminal only, with the keys you created in `apps->gedit-2->plugins`

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting `terminal.py` for Ubuntu 16.04, it seems it loads some legacy profile:

```py
def get_profile_settings(self):
    profiles = self.settings_try_new("org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList")

    if not profiles:
        default_path = "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:" + profiles.get_string("default") + "/"
        settings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path("org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile",
                                              default_path)
    else:
        settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal")

    return settings
```

Inspecting `org.gnome.terminal.legacy.profiles:` in `dconf-editor`, there was such a profile. [After deleting it](https://askubuntu.com/a/85755/158442) with:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

I could change settings in `org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal` and have them take effect. For `background-color`, I had to disable `use-theme-colours` first.

Answer (score 0):

in 13.04, the gconf-editor path to the properties has changed to:
org -> gnome -> gedit -> terminal