# How can I change the color of the text in a terminal embedded in GEdit?

Tags: gedit

I am having trouble using the terminal in GEdit since the text-color is white on gray background. I can not find an option to change anything for that terminal anywhere. How can I change it? N.B. The python terminal is fine.

Obligatory screenshot:

[image: Notice the unreadable text in the terminal below]

Comment: I changed the background-color/ foreground-color exactely as they are shown in your screen-shot but nothing changes.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate) question has good answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal/162009#comment542255_162009

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Questions seems to be so unpopular that I received the "Tumbleweed bagde". Awesome!

1. Open dconf-editor
2. Navigate to `org - gnome - gedit - plugins - terminal`
3. Change the values background-color and foreground-color (this is the text color) to your liking
4. Also make sure to untick the `use-theme-colors` box. *(Thanks to comment by Hibou57)*

Since a picture says more than a thousand words:

[image: Dconf-editor entry for gedit]

Comment: I tried the solution suggested by Ingo, but it changed nothing, even after I closed and re‑opened the session, and I checked the colours I choose are OK (`#000000` for the background and `#FFFFFF` for the foreground). -- edit -- In addition to what Ingo said, you also have to **uncheck the `use-theme-colors` option**. This need to be said.