# Gedit embeded terminal showing both background and foreground in white color

Tags: command-line, gedit

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04`.I am using `Gedit` with one of the `plugin called Embeded Terminal` which is used to place the terminal attached at the `bottom part of the Gedit`.Now my problem is in that embeded terminal `both the screen background and text is in white color`,so its difficult to see any text there.I tried to `configure the fonts in dconf editor`.But there was not any good result.Here I am attaching the screenshot of the configuration of dconf editor that I have changed.So please help me to solve this.Any help will be highly appreciable.[image: dconf configuration of embeded terminal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many characters in your color defs. Change background color to `#FFFFFF` and foreground color to `#000000`. You can use an online tool such as this one, http://www.colorpicker.com/ to pick the colors you want. You can also use color names, like `red`, `black` or `blue`. Also, in case others are having this issue, make sure you uncheck `use-theme-colors`, as it is checked by default.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems to be a ["won't-fix" bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/946095), another user says he solved: [How can I change the color of the text in a terminal embedded in GEdit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103616/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-text-in-a-terminal-embedded-in-gedit)

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf-editor by `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

Open dconf-editor, go to `org-gnome-gedit`. Change `background-color` and `foreground-color`. Then don't forget to **uncheck** `use-theme-color`