# Can I change the gedit shell output colors?

Tags: themes, gedit

With the help of (answers to) questions like [Make gedit embedded terminal colours the same as the default terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal/162009) and 
[How can I change the color of the text in a terminal embedded in GEdit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103616/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-text-in-a-terminal-embedded-in-gedit) my gedit terminal now respects the theme colors (actually: that isn't true. The terminal seems to use Cobalt no matter what color scheme I set in the preferences, but at least I can read it.)

The "Shell Output" tab, however, is still all red letters on a white background and I don't see where that is being set. How do I get gedit's "Shell Output" tab to respect the theme colors?

Using gedit - Version 3.8.3

Comment: Actually it is black color for stdout-type output and red for stderr. What bothers me is that even if the program tries to produce colors (like now `gcc` does), they are ignored by the gedit output.