# Gedit Embedded Terminal Uses Incorrect Palette

Tags: gnome-terminal, gedit

I've followed the advice to turn off "use-theme-colors" and also set a custom background color in my embedded gedit terminal. But somehow, the palette setting is ignored and colors show as only black and white. As usual, a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: depiction of problem]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You should probably [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to it:

[Make gedit embedded terminal colours the same as the default terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal)

Make sure you also read the very last post, as only after applying that I had my problem completely resolved.

Comment: This is a pretty annoying bug, but this fix will work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Having the exact same problem here, I'd like to be able to use the Tango palette like the gnome terminal.

Alas, you can at least get some semblance of colours if you just select the palette field and give it a blank value. This will effectively force the default (the standard, loud Linux console palette).

[image: Screenshot]