# Configuring the gedit embeded terminal

Tags: command-line, gedit

I have two problems with my gedit embeded terminal:

- First my terminal line is white and black, and I really want it to be like the Ubuntu terminal line that is purple:

**Embeded terminal:**
[image]

**Regular terminal:**
[image]

To fix this problem I read a thread that explains how to change colors, but it failed. I also read the thread they were pointing to: [Gedit Embedded Terminal Uses Incorrect Palette](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152348/gedit-embedded-terminal-uses-incorrect-palette)

- When I open the embeded terminal, it also opens it in the home directory, but I want it to open on the folder of the file that is actually opened, like in Kate. How do I do it?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/67593/83046)?

Comment: You should split your questions into two separate questions so that they are easy to search for.

Comment: @green7: Yes, the link you provide is given in my thread. As for making two questions, the second one would probably be to short, but thanks :P

Comment: will look into it.

Comment: Any news in this area?

Comment: What are the values of `foreground-color`, `background-color`, and `palette` as mentioned in `gconf-editor` (_apps_ > _gnome_terminal_)? Also please post values (or preferable screenshot) from `dconf-editor` (_org_ > _gnome_ > _gedit_ > _plugins_ > _terminal_).

Comment: my dconf values are the same as my gconf values. I copied everything from gconf to dconf, as stated in the tutorials I presented. 

I will show you guys images as soon as I get my machine back from fixing!