# Make Gedit embedded terminal colors match global theme? (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, themes, gnome-terminal, gedit, plugins

The embedded terminal of Gedit in my 16.04 session is not following the default ubuntu theme, and does not seem to be configurable in any way.

More precisely, it follows the username@hostname color of the ubuntu theme (some kind of bright green) but the background is plain white (should be 'aubergine') and the text is black (should be white).

This problem [had been addressed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal) for earlier versions of ubuntu, but in 16.04 things seem to have changed:

- there is no Gedit entry in `gconf-editor`
- editing directly the colors in `dconf-editor` has no effect whatsoever
- clearing the plugin's palette in is prohibited, one can only enter an empty `[]`

So this is NOT a duplicate: none of the earlier solutions work and there seems to be something specific to 16.04 with respect to this problem. My impressions is that there is an issue with the way `gconf` settings are handled, maybe a bug in the terminal plugin script `terminal.py` (located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins`) but this exceeds my competence, so any help is welcome.

Comment: I posted [an answer for 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/872429/158442). Try it out.

Comment: Just did, no luck. You seem to be digging in the right direction though.

Comment: @Marc I had the same problem and fixed it by commenting out the if statement shown in the [answer by muru](http://askubuntu.com/a/872429/658916) in the terminal.py file (mine was located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/). If you only keep the line that sets the settings to the ones defined by the dconf editor, it should work. Make sure that it has the proper identation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I tried (can't post the code in comments apparently?) and the terminal plugin won't launch with the commented code. The script sets profile to "self.settings_try_new("org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList")" apparently. But there is no such entry in the dconf tree. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @Marc I think your identation might be off in the code. Identation defines scopes in python code, like curly brackets do in C. I'm going to write a proper answer to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/872429/658916) of user muru, I have found a workaround which worked for me. First, find the python script `terminal.py` located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/`. Or you can enter the command `locate terminal.py` in the Ubuntu terminal. In this python script, you can find the following code block:

```py
def get_profile_settings(self):
    profiles = self.settings_try_new("org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList")

    if not profiles:
        default_path = "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:" + profiles.get_string("default") + "/"
        settings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path("org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile",
                                              default_path)
    else:
        settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal")

    return settings
```

Now change this to:

```py
def get_profile_settings(self):
    profiles = self.settings_try_new("org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList")

#    if not profiles:
#        default_path = "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:" + profiles.get_string("default") + "/"
#        settings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path("org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile",
#                                              default_path)
#    else:

    settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal")

    return settings
```

Now the settings entered via the `dconf-editor` should work. Be aware that you might have to change it again in the future if the `gedit-plugins` package gets updated.

Comment: Problem with this is that these changes will be lost when the package is next upgraded (which might not be for a long time, though).

Comment: Finally something that works! Probably worth mentioning issue/fix this to the gnome team.