# How to change the colours of the embedded terminal in gedit in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, gedit

I tried following the steps on the answers to this question: [Make gedit embedded terminal colours the same as the default terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal)

However, none of them work.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I tried changing the settings using dconf-editor but the changes are not reflected in gedit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today and stumbled on this question. Sadly it had no answer. Happily, I manged to figure it out. HTH someone else.

I'm using an Ubuntu 16.04 VM, and followed the same tutorial, and had the same results.

The issue lies here, in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/terminal.py` lines 88-98:

```
def get_profile_settings(self):
profiles = self.settings_try_new("org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList")

if profiles:
    default_path = "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:" + profiles.get_string("default") + "/"
    settings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path("org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile",
                                          default_path)
else:
    settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal")

return settings
```

When the plugin gets the terminal settings, it first checks the dconf-editor path for the default terminal settings, which, if yours is like mine, only has the `use-theme-transparency` setting. As a result, the embedded terminal has no settings to actually use. I figure the hard way to fix this would be to replicate the keys in org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal into the `org.gnome.Terminal.ProfileList`. Instead, open `terminal.py`, comment out the if statement, and force the settings to use the `org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal` settings.

```
    def get_profile_settings(self):
    profiles = self.settings_try_new("org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList")

#        if profiles:
#            default_path = "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:" + profiles.get_string("default") + "/"
#            settings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path("org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile",
#                                                  default_path)
#        else:
#            settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal")

    settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal")
    return settings
```

Once you restart, you should have a black and white terminal-

[image]